# silly yet sensible concern about single page web application architecture

Tags: php, javascript, apache-flex, laravel, single-page-application

I am starting up a new web application and I have this very silly concern, thought I will clarify from all of you guys.

This application will be a **single page web application** and will be developed in Html,JS/Flex as front end and PHP as back end. So I have two choices

1. Keep all the application logic in client side i.e (JS/Flex) and use PHP just for input and output of data to Database.
2. Use JS/Flex only for UI and keep all the application logic in PHP, which will be consumed as independent services.

Both have pros and cons like

- If I go with first option, the user experience of the application will be smooth. (as this involves very less client server interaction)
- where as If I go with second option, the application logic will be there in PHP, which I can later expose as API, in case I want others to use the same API and build custom application.

But I am not able to argue on the pros and cons of both and finalise on one. Please help, hoping you must have faced similar problems in your development career.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on the application. If some data need to be persistent, then of course you should store it server-side. If not, local database is indeed better.

Comment: with a proper single page app you would make the backend an api that you call from the frontend.  It's called eating your own dog food.

Comment: you can also publish a client-side api.

Comment: @abc123 you should expand and post that as the answer.... that is the right one.

Comment: @Orangepill what do you really mean by client-side api in this context?

Comment: I mean a client side library for interacting with your service.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest and prefer to go for `option 2` for following reasons
1. As you said you can expose the API later.
2. It will be more secure as all the application logic will be handled by PHP.

Comment: nothing precludes him using option one and leveraging his own api from the front code.

Comment: Thanks Runish! yes, true. do you see any other advantages with this? As option 2 might affect the user experience little bit, I am searching for solid advantages which counters the disadvantages.

Comment: I am not sure what your application is and how it will be used. But the solid advantage is the API. Because once you have a full fledged API you can build different mobile app, tablet app and ofcourse web app using same API.

Comment: @Runish, however i am agreed with approach 2, But still if user experience is more needed now and API is only in mind thing, Then first may be more practical approach.

Comment: @kuldeep yes it of-course depends on what exactly takes more precedence for your application. We were just talking about the advantages of both the options.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of *[design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food)* however since you are interested in the possibility of making **API**'s later the most appropriate for you would be a form of your *option 2*.

> Use JS/Flex only for UI and keep all the application logic in PHP, which will be consumed as independent services.

Simply make a front end using one of the following technologies for **single page application** front end UI:

- [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)
- [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/)
- [marionette](http://marionettejs.com/)
- flex

[image: Difficulty]

Then make all your business logic into `RESTful API` calls written in `PHP` or `Python` or any other `backend language`.

If these services allow for full `CRUD` and not just `Read` I recommend using `OAuth` to secure your services to only allow authorized users to `Create, Update, and Delete`.  You can just use an [OAuth PHP library](https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/).

The reason for this is it allows you to create any other applications and just have to rebuild the UI and not have to remake the business logic in every language `(C, C++, objective C, C#, Python, PHP, JavaScript, Ruby, etc.)`.  Then when you release the `API` to the public they will call your `OAuth service` with a valid username and password (given by the user) and will be able to make a rich full featured application because you have now [eating your own dog food](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food).  This is a very important concept, although it might take you longer to develop you won't have to `re-architect` and thereby `re-develop` or `re-factor` a lot of code.